# Unable to detect a failed print on a remote system using ssh

Tags: ssh, cups, exit-status, printer

Below is my code on linux that prints a PDF on a remote MACOS system.

```
echo "Printing ssh -p 3335 ibrahimince@localhost 'lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series $HOMEDIR/Printed/$NEWFILE'";

echo "Remote File details are:"
ssh -p 3335 ibrahimince@localhost "ls -ltr $HOMEDIR/Printed/$NEWFILE"

until ssh -p 3335 ibrahimince@localhost "lp -o media=A5 -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series $HOMEDIR/Printed/$NEWFILE" >/home/system/efendibey.de/invoices/send4print/printererror.log 2>&1
do

echo "Exit Code of the command was: $?"
echo "Send email that there is an issue printing invoice for the below file. Issue is: `cat /home/system/efendibey.de/invoices/send4print/printererror.log`"
ls -ltr $FILE >>/home/system/efendibey.de/invoices/send4print/printererror.log

mail -s "PRINTER SERVICE FAIL ALERT. PLEASE CHECK YOUR PRINTER!!" mohtashim@digiklug.com < /home/system/efendibey.de/invoices/send4print/mailbody.txt
sleep 20

done

echo "Print successful. Deleting $FILE"
rm $FILE;

fi
```

Here are the logs for a particular print `online_delivery_10001333.pdf`.

```
Printing ssh -p 3335 ibrahimince@localhost 'lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series /Users/ibrahimince/Printed/online_delivery_10001333.pdf'
Remote File details are:
-rw-r--r--  1 ibrahimince  staff  11496 Aug  2 19:29 /Users/ibrahimince/Printed/online_delivery_10001333.pdf
Print successful. Deleting /home/system/efendibey.de/invoices/send4print/online_delivery_10001333.pdf
```

The logs say that the print was successful and the return code was 0(successful).

But, the print actually failed, and below is the snapshot of the same.

Error: `Gestoppt - Can't open "/private/var/spool/cups/d02183-001.`

[image]

How can I refine my code so to make sure the print was actually successful?

Below is the `lpstat -t` logs:

```
Remote File details are:
-rw-r--r--  1 ibrahimince  staff  11507 Aug 18 20:00 /Users/ibrahimince/Printed/online_delivery_10001333.pdf
scheduler is running
system default destination: Brother_HL_L2350DW_series
device for Brother_HL_L2350DW_series: dnssd://Brother%20HL-L2350DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local./?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-2c6fc95df52e
device for Brother_MFC_L3750CDW_series_b_3_Fax: dnssd://Brother%20MFC-L3750CDW%20series._ipp._tcp.local./?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-3c2af4dd8a75
device for Canon_TS700_series: ippusb://Canon%20TS700%20series._ipp._tcp.local./?uuid=00000000-0000-1000-8000-00186d1376d5
device for Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw: dnssd://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20M5526cdw._ipps._tcp.local./?uuid=4509a320-00a6-0073-00bb-002507512ad9
device for Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw_b_3_Fax: dnssd://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20M5526cdw._ipps._tcp.local./?uuid=4509a320-00a6-0073-00bb-002507512ad9
Brother_HL_L2350DW_series accepting requests since Wed Aug 18 20:00:24 2021
Brother_MFC_L3750CDW_series_b_3_Fax accepting requests since Tue Jun 29 17:04:09 2021
Canon_TS700_series accepting requests since Wed Aug 18 18:34:42 2021
Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw accepting requests since Thu Jul  8 12:30:45 2021
Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw_b_3_Fax accepting requests since Thu Jul  8 12:28:58 2021
printer Brother_HL_L2350DW_series is idle.  enabled since Wed Aug 18 20:00:24 2021
        Can't open "/private/var/spool/cups/d03050-001."
printer Brother_MFC_L3750CDW_series_b_3_Fax is idle.  enabled since Tue Jun 29 17:04:09 2021
printer Canon_TS700_series is idle.  enabled since Wed Aug 18 18:34:42 2021
printer Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw disabled since Thu Jul  8 12:30:45 2021 -
        reason unknown
printer Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw_b_3_Fax is idle.  enabled since Thu Jul  8 12:28:58 2021
Brother_HL_L2350DW_series-3050 ibrahimince      12288   Wed Aug 18 20:00:24 2021
Print successful. Deleting
```

Comment: “Print successful” actually only means that the data was accepted by the print spooler. After that it gets sent to the printer, and if that fails, the error appears in logs but there's no convenient way to get it in a script. I think you have to obtain the job ID and poll its status. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62916/cups-check-if-print-successful-either-python-or-in-system for a similar problem (not an exact duplicate because that one was in python on linux, and sh on macos will make the answer slightly different).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' there are solutions for python but I still could not find any solution to check if my print was successful in shell scripting.

Comment: Why do you ssh several times instead of running a more complex script in a single ssh session?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen that approach can also be taken but my query is about how to detect a successful print in shell script.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the exit status of `lp` only shows that the job was successfully queued. The manual says that an exit status > 0 means "No output device was available, or an error occurred." (The "an error occurred" is a bit cryptic.)

A quick solution would be to use the output of `ssh -p 3335 ibrahimince@localhost lpstat -t` and parse that.

Comment: i m getting the following error `ssh -p 3335 ibrahimince@localhost "lpstat -ot"
lpstat: Invalid destination name in list "t".` I tried ` `ssh -p 3335 ibrahimince@localhost "lpstat -o -t"` but this or any other command sometimes hangs !! and never returns.

Comment: the `-o` was a typo; I meant `lpstat -t`. You could try other options (see `man lpstat`) if they give you a better idea of  your printer status.

Comment: Dullalaart upon your suggestion i enabled `lpstat -t` and updating the output for the error seen in the log. I m however, not sure how can I determine which file failed to print and how can I resend the file for printing.